# Using NOT LIKE in WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql

The User Table is like below,

```
name  | username    | email 
--------------------------------- 
 Joe  |    joe      | joe@mail.com      
--------------------------------- 
 John |    ABC\john | john@abc.com      
--------------------------------- 
 Kate |    kate     | kate@mail.com 
--------------------------------- 
 Ron  |    ABC\ron  | ron@abc.com  
---------------------------------
```

The mySQL query to select all fields from the table where the username in the table doesn't start with "ABC\". Since the user logs in to an application using the active directory credentials, the user name is stored in to with Domain\Username (Eg: ABC\username). I tried to create the query but it is not working.

```
Select * from User where username NOT LIKE 'ABC\\\\%_'
```

But is not working.It is pulling all the user records.

```
name  | username    | email 
--------------------------------- 
 Joe  |    joe      | joe@mail.com      
--------------------------------- 
 John |    ABC\john | john@abc.com      
--------------------------------- 
 Kate |    kate     | kate@mail.com 
--------------------------------- 
 Ron  |    ABC\ron  | ron@abc.com  
---------------------------------
```

But I need users whose username doesn't starts with "ABC\".

```
name  | username    | email 
--------------------------------- 
 John |    ABC\john | john@abc.com      
--------------------------------- 
 Ron  |    ABC\ron  | ron@abc.com  
---------------------------------
```

I tried to filter with respect to the email address as  below it is working fine

```
Select * from User where email NOT LIKE '_%@abc.com'
```

I am new to queries and can manage to write simple queries but this one I am not sure if I am following the correct way.

Comment: Please edit your question with some examples of what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: Works ok for me - can you show some example data in your table

Comment: Are you sending your query directly to the server or is there some transformation along the way? I am wondering if your \\\\ sequence gets modified before it reaches the server?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using

Comment: Also where are you running this command from? Is this from a web page/.net application/MySQL workbench/commandline?

Comment: I am using this in an Outsystems platform. But some body gave the answer `Select * from User where username NOT LIKE 'ABC\%'` that works here. As you said I was following [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) here it was not working.

Comment: Glad you got it working. It looks like Outsystems maybe preprocessing the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure who posted the answer

```
Select * from User where username NOT LIKE 'ABC\%'
```

that works here. I was following [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) it was not working, not sure why. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Your Query works fine for me. I think your problem is using backslash in a string that would be your query.

```
            $not_like= "ABC\\%";
            $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `email` NOT LIKE ?");
            $statement->bind_param('s', $not_like);
            $statement->execute();
            $result = $statement->get_result();
            while($get_users = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo($get_users['username']);
            }
            $result2->free();
```

Comment: OP has said why there is a backslash in the username string - his query should work as far as I can see and does with my table.

Comment: @PaulF his query is fine, but I think while he is using backslash in the the string, he can't pass it to mysql directly. Using bind_param is the best way

Comment: I have asked how he is running the query - as tomsv said it may be being modified before it gets to the server.

Comment: @PaulF so the backslash wouldn't recognize as a special character and just one backslash will works for him.

Comment: maybe Outsource does pre-processing to create the correct query string.